# Editting a string in resources

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

how would I edit a string in the resources of my project? I get this error when I try it:

> Property or indexer 'Project.Properties.Resources.ExternalIp' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

This is what I do:

```
Resources.ExternalIp = utf8.GetString(webClient.DownloadData("http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Properties.Ressources` are readonly ("compiled"), you have to use `Properties.Settings` & put the Scope to "User" so it will be 'ReadWrite'

```
Project.Properties.Settings.Default.ExternalIp = utf8.GetString(webClient.DownloadData("http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp"));
Project.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Resources are not supposed to be written to; they're embedded in the executable, so changing them would involve modifying the executable.

From your code, it looks like you actually need [application settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx), not resources.